# Memory management in coredata NSEntityDescription

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm manually creating a CoreData entity description (for a library I'm writing) and I'm using language like this:

```
NSEntityDescription * entity = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];
[entity setName:@"Name"];
[entity setManagedObjectClassName:@"Name"];

NSAttributeDescription * att = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
[att setName:@"att"];
[att setAttributeType:NSStringAttributeType];
[entity setProperties:@[att]];

coreDataModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] init];
[coreDataModel setEntities:@[entity]];
```

`coreDataModel` is an instance variable of my class: I'm releasing it in the `dealloc` method. However, XCode's Analyze is complaining that I might be leaking the `NSEntityDescription` and `NSAttributeDescription`. I couldn't find anything in the docs that says that I can safely release them: any one know if the `NSManagedObjectModel` retains as necessary, or do I need to keep them around myself?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At least you add these objects to a collection in this case NSArray. All collections in Cocoa retain the objects they hold so you can release them with no worries after setting the model entities.

The static analyzer is "over reacting" sometimes anyway ;) If you have any doubts that you leak memory use Instruments.

Comment: What I said... You almost ALWAYS follow the rule that: you release what you own.

Comment: Try to write some complicated multithreaded code and see that Static Analyzer is a complete fail. It works very well for simple stuff anyway

Answer (score 0):

You alloc init them, you release them. You add them to an array that is then passed to the MOM and that will keep the objects alive there